# Convolution by differentiation property of convolution

Tags: convolution, continuous-signals, homework

This is the question

[image]

when i am trying to do it by the deravative property of convolution 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Differentiation like this

[image]
Actual answer should come like this

> $$y(t)=
> \begin{cases}0, & \text{for }t < 0 \\
> 7-3t, & \text{for } 0<t<1 \\
> 5-t, & \text{for } 1<t<5 \\
> 7, & \text{for } t>5
> \end{cases}$$

**i am getting answer -6 at t=4 bu the actual answer should come 1**

> P.S:-
>   Please dont give me alternative method to solve this i know it already instead tell me whats wrong i am doing in this method 
>   also i know i am violating the policy by putting the image but i will edit it lator in text form .

Comment: Now you've got your answer :-) finally !

Comment: [Related post on dsp.meta](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1535/23301).

Comment: $u(t)$ would need to be defined.

Comment: $u(t)$ is standard unit step signal and $r(t)$ is unit ramp signal@OlliNiemitalo

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all let me state that, the property of differentiation under (convolution) integral operator may not be holding true for arbitrary signals but only for some subclass, such as absolutely integrable ones. That's stated in the **wikipedia** link OP provides about convolution. All I can make sense from that statement is that interchange of differentiation and integration is only possible if the integral is convergent. That's formal mathematics and I'm not very sure whether that applies to generalized functions, such as $u(t)$ and $\delta(t)$ as well. So I'll leave the discussion to mathematicians for a moment and proceed with the solution, treating the functions as if they're **well behaving**.

So far you've correctly obtained the signal $y(t)'$ from the differentiation of convolution property as: $$y(t)' = h(t)' \star x(t)  = -3 u(t) + 2u(t-1) + u(t-5)$$

Now it comes to proper integration of $y(t)'$ to obtain $y(t)$ which was the most misleading step; $$ \int_{-\infty}^{t} y(\tau)' d\tau = \int_{-\infty}^{t} -3 u(t) + 2u(t-1) + u(t-5) d\tau$$

the **left side** evaluates as;

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{t} y(\tau)' d\tau = \int_{-\infty}^{t} dy d\tau = y(\tau)+C |_{-\infty}^{t} = (y(t)+C)-(y(-\infty)+C) = y(t)-y(-\infty) $$

Now here I shall make a few simple comments. As below we argue with @msm whether this is a **definite** integral or an **indefinite** one? He seems to claim it as an idefinite one with constant of integration at the output. (I don't actually know it because he doesn't put his equation there inspite of all my attempts, also he seems(?) to delete that comment as well? Rather he says it's simple to see. I don't know. It's always better to make it clear when **requested** to avoid any **confusion**. Of course this is a **definite** integral with clear limits on it, hence at the output you won't have a **constant of integration** whatsoever. The integrand is antiderivatived, and evaluated at the limits and subtracted so that the constant of integration is cancelled. What remains there as $y(-\infty)$ the integrand evaluated at the limits. For **causal** systems and signals applied, $y(-\infty)$ is by defintion zero, hence it's ignored, but when you have a **noncausal** system (like in the example system with $h(t) = u(-t-1)$ you may not ignore it and hence the term $y(-\infty)$ remains.

The **right side** of the equation is integrated as follows:
$$  = \int_{-\infty}^{t} -3 u(\tau) + 2u(\tau-1) + u(\tau-5) d\tau  = \int_{0}^{t} -3 u(\tau) + 2u(\tau-1) + u(\tau-5) d\tau $$

$$  = (-3 r(t) + 2r(t-1) + r(t-5) + C)-(-3 r(0) + 2r(0-1) + r(0-5) + C)$$
$$  = -3 r(t) + 2r(t-1) + r(t-5) $$

Where we have indeed antiderivated each integrand and subtracted their evaluation at $\tau=t$ and $\tau=0$, the latter one all providing $0$

Hence we have;
$$ y(t) = -3 r(t) + 2r(t-1) + r(t-5) + y(-\infty) $$

At this point it's worth noting that, the output $y(t)$ depends on itself due to the $y(-\infty)$ term. Where you can fortunately (easily) evaluate it from the convolution integral as $$y(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(t-\tau)x(\tau)d\tau $$ as $t \rightarrow -\infty$ resulting in;
$$ y(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(-\infty-\tau)x(\tau)d\tau = y(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 1 x(\tau)d\tau = 7 $$

Hence the solution becomes, $$y(t) = 7 -3 r(t) + 2r(t-1) + r(t-5) $$
and finally $$y(4) = 7 - 3 r(4) + 2 r(3) + r(-1) = 7 - 3 \times 4 + 2 \times 3 + 1 \times 0 = 1$$

Below you can see the verification by **direct evaluation** of the colvolution integral.

(**EDIT**: see the first paragraph to get the point)
As warned by the OP, that the differentiation property under the convolution is not valid for the signal $h(t) = u(-t-1)$, so we then resort to direct evaluation to check the answer.

$$y(t) = x(t) \star h(t) = x(t) \star u(-t-1)$$

The graphical method provides the easiest evaluation of this integral for particular output value of $t=4$ as:

$$y(4) = \int_{\tau= 5}^{\tau=6} x(\tau)h(4-\tau) d\tau = \int_{\tau= 5}^{\tau=6} 1 \cdot 1 d\tau = 1 $$

So the requested value is: $y(4) = 1$ , hence you are right the answer is $y(4) = 1$ and (**EDIT**: see the first paragraph to get the point) [it seems the differentiation property is not applicable for arbitrary signals but those which are absolutely integrable.]

An example to see the diferentiation property is; $x(t) = u(t) - u(t-1)$ and $h(t) = u(t) - u(t-1)$  where we have $y(t)' = u(t) - 2u(t-1) + u(t-2)$ and the differentiation property yields: $$y(t)' = h(t)' \star x(t) = (\delta(t) - \delta(t-1)) \star x(t) = u(t) - 2u(t-2) + u(t-2)$$

Sorry for the confusion...

Comment: sir i have one doubt wikipedia say this differention property applicable only when the both the signal should be absolute integrable but here unit step is not absolute integrable so how this property is applied here ?

Comment: Wait sorry sir the answer is not -6 its 1 because i getting 1 by general convolution method

Comment: sir the answer you are giving is not the correct answer, thats whats i am getting but thats wrong, answer should come  1 at t=4 i verified it by general convolution method

Comment: Yes you are right. Direct convolution results in $y(4)=1$. Let me correct the answer.

Comment: sir this property what wikipedia saying that signal should be absolute integrable is not applying everywhere because i used this property even with the non aboolute integrable like if u take $u(t+1)*r(t-2)$ then i will get right result by differentiating one of the signal even though the signal is not absolute integrable.here r(t-2) is the unit ramp signal.

Comment: @Rohi you are confusing me. Now there are 2 possiblities. 1-) Diff. rule applies for **all** signals, but here somehow we can't get the correct result :-), shame on us! OR  2-) Diff. Rule only applies only for absolutely integrable signals, but then you have a counter example ? (but a single counter example here cannot disprove Diff.rule). Note that in order for the diff rule to hold, the orders of int. and diff. must be changing, but thi sis permitted iff the integral converges.

Comment: @Rohit Your answer is correct, you are only missing a constant in your integration. Refer to my answer for a solution based on differentiation.

Comment: Down-voting for "the differentiation property under the convolution is not valid for the signal $h(t)=u(−t−1)$" which is wrong and the fact that the (originally wrong) answer does not address the OP's question that says "P.S:- Please dont give me alternative method to solve this i know it already instead tell me whats wrong i am doing in this method..."

Comment: Comments flagged for "Learn it well, before making noise... " and the response "you haven't answered any of my 10?? questions" after asking many questions and receiving appropriate answers.

Comment: @Fat32 This is not appropriate and you won't get credit for leaving wrong answers and wrong/rude comments on other correct answers and down-voting. It is best to fix your mistakes. Didn't you finally realize there is no definite integral?. I really can't help you with that anymore (sorry).

Comment: @msm There's no **wrong** answer here, neither yours nor mine. I have already **improved** my answer. And you still claim $C$ as **constant of integration** of an **indefinite** integral ?  Please see my answer now... these are your words *Didn't you finally realize there is no definite integral?*

Comment: @Fat32 I have asked moderators to revert your answer to **reversion 5** (before I left my answer). You have significantly changed your answer based on mine (which you have down-voted). It is an almost verbatim copy (plus some extensions). This approach is what you have claimed is wrong explicitly in your post (Rev-5), and sought an alternative approach.

Comment: @msm You are not aware of what you are saying. You still claim that there is **NO** **definite integral** here? Your comment is above. So your solution is (probably) based on an **indefinite** integral? But my solution is based on **definite** integral, so they ARE **different** answers according to your definition. I have changed my answer **because** you HESITATED to improve yours. You didnt include the integral, I asked you 5 times? This is a shame !

Comment: @Fat32 I am aware of what I say and what you do. I leave this to the moderators. It is very easy for them to handle the situation. Please don't take it personal. I think I should do something to prevent similar "tactics" on this website in the future. won't leave more comments (sorry). Have a nice day!

Comment: I have more than 250 genuine answers here. I don't need any one of yours, eventhough I've seen so many good ones. Please don't take it personal either. I'm still confused if these are **definite** integrals or **indefinite** ones? I belive they are definite (with variable limit $t$ and improper limit $-\infty$ hence at the output there's no constant of integration. Clear. But an indefinite integral happens without any limits for **anti-derivative** operations, therefore with a constant of integration $C$. Clear. @PeterK. are they definite or indefinite? who can tell us?

Comment: @MarcusMüller. This msm guy really bugged me now! :) Not only accussing me of stealing his *inexistant* answer, but calling those integrals as **indefinite**. Now I'm really bugged. Aren't they **definite** integrals (with variable limits) I have checked many resources know and they all show definite integral with **fixed** limits and indefinite integrals without any limits, but neither define the type of an integral with variable limits :)!! what's it called now? I still consider it as definite.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I mean we call $\int_a^b f'(\tau)d\tau = f(b) - f(a)$ this as definite integral, so we call this $\int_a^x f'(\tau)d\tau = f(x) - f(a)$ as definite integral as well? don't we ?

Comment: @Fat32 sir first you got $y(t)-y(-\infty)$ then you should get the the value at $y(-\infty)$ but you have calcuted lator on $y(\infty)$ why i am really confused please help me?

Comment: @Rohit You should be confused after all those changes in this thread and its repeated wrong and misleading statements. Right now, this fully plagiarized post makes you confused even more, because there are unnecessary fillers (like 7−3×4+2×3+1×0=1 and whether something is definite or indefinite and so on) to build a fake argument. If you are really looking for your mistake in your post, my answer has provided it. From your solution, I guess you can understand the point. But you are welcome to ask questions, otherwise.

Comment: @Rohit Of course that's a typo. If you follow the argumentation on the above paragraph it's the function $y(\tau)$ evaluated at the lower limit $\tau = -\infty$ hence it should be $y(-\infty)$. Now your question answeres in crystal clear with **every** step explained.

Comment: @Fat32 sir Now its a convincing thanks alot....but why did someone  downvote my question i mean earlier there was 2 upvotes

Comment: @Rohit I'm glad you we could finally resolve your problem. That was a nice one by the way, requires a careful mind to perform the integration which is so easily overlooked in general. I don't know who downvoted your question (but I can guess who would do it :-)) ) sometimes people do it, don't worry. Your homework questions were really interesting, and I'm glad if I could be helpful.